# Stopping a Handler Based Runnable after AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, handler, runnable

I'm fairly new to Android programming.

Simple Explanation for my problem:

I have an async task to collect JSON based data after every 20 seconds based on this runnable:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mTask = new JSONParse();
        mTask.execute();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 20000);
    }
};
```

How do I stop it when I want to?

Detailed Explanation for my Problem:

Within this Async Task, I check if the data is available, and if not available, I go back to the mainscreen by first invoking

```
mTask.cancel(true);
```

and then in the onCancelled() method as follows:

```
protected void onCancelled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCancelled();
        mTask.cancel(false);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        displayWrongPhoneToast();
    }
```

where displayWrongPhoneToast() is a simple function as follows:

```
public void displayWrongPhoneToast() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Sorry! Enter at least one field to continue.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(TabActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The problem I have is, the handler is causing the runnable to execute in the background, which is making the application request data over and over again and causing the displayWrongPhoneToast() to execute over and over again.

I tried some methods I found online to stop the runnable, but it refuses to. Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call

```
handler.removeCallbacks(r).
```

Comment: Yeah, this works. Although, if I type a valid entry in my main screen, and then press the back button to come back to the main screen, then the correct process never terminates, and continues running in the background every 20 seconds. How do I stop that?

Comment: Good if it works, then please accept the answer as correct. Your second question seems unrelated (how should I know without some code) and I think you should better open a new question ...